# Possible to dynamically redraw single plot of multiple shown together?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, graphics

I am attempting to create a tool to visualize gradient, eigenvector, and eigenvalue information for a 2D surface.  I want to show a contour plot of an inputted function and overlay the gradient and eigenvectors based at a point selected by a Locator.  The problem is when I move the Locator point the contour plot redraws -- which is slow.  So I'd like for the gradient and eigenvector information to change but the contour plot to stay (unless the function is changed).

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{},
    p1 = ContourPlot[expr /. {x -> x, y -> y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> 20];

    grad = D[expr, {{x, y}}];
    ngrad = grad /. {x -> Dynamic[pt[[1]]], y -> Dynamic[pt[[2]]]} ;
    p2 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{pt, pt + ngrad}]}];

    Show[p1, p2]
  ],
  {{pt, {1, 1}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, Locator},
  {{expr, 2*x*Cos[y] - x*y + 10, "f(x,y)"}, InputField},
  {locx, pt[[1]], InputField},
  {locy, pt[[2]], InputField},
  {locval, expr /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}, InputField}]
```

I expect this can be done using Dynamic, but everything I've tried so far has not worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere wrapping `pt` in Dynamic allows it to be updated without triggering changes in the `CountourPlot`, which is independent of `pt`:

```
Manipulate[Module[{},
  p1 = ContourPlot[expr /. {x -> x, y -> y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Contours -> 20]; grad = D[expr, {{x, y}}]; 
  ngrad = grad /. {x -> Dynamic[pt[[1]]], y -> Dynamic[pt[[2]]]};
  p2 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{Dynamic[pt], Dynamic[pt + ngrad]}]}]; 
  Show[p1, p2]],
  {{pt, {1, 1}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, Locator}, {{expr, 2*x*Cos[y] - x*y + 10, "f(x,y)"}, 
  InputField}, {locx, pt[[1]], InputField}, {locy, pt[[2]], 
  InputField}, {locval, expr /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}, InputField}]
```

See "Using Dynamic Inside Manipulate", the second section of [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) for details.

Comment: This works.  Thank you very much for the help!  I'll spend more time with the documentation.

Comment: Glad this is what you needed.  I do recommend you take the 10 minutes needed to read the introductory Tour, under Help.